# OpenGL linker error on MinGW

Tags: windows, opengl, g++, mingw, linker-errors

I tryies to init OpenGL on windows without GLFW ... her some relevant code:

```
#include <windows.h>
//...
  if(!(g_hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))
    return false;

  if(!(iPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(g_hDC, &pfdPixelFormat)))
    return false;

  if(!SetPixelFormat(g_hDC, iPixelFormat, &pfdPixelFormat))
    return false;

  if(!(g_hRC = wglCreateContext(g_hDC)))
    return false;

  if(!wglMakeCurrent(g_hDC, g_hRC))
    return false;
//...
```

when I compile with mingw32-g++ -Wall -O2 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lopengl32 -mwindows Init.c I get following errors:

```
Temp\cclcIFFB.o:init.c:(.text+0x281): undefined reference to `_wglCreateContext@4'
Temp\cclcIFFB.o:init.c:(.text+0x2a0): undefined reference to `_wglMakeCurrent@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why this linker error acours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your `Init.c` *before* the `-lopengl32`:

```
mingw32-g++ -Wall -O2 Init.c -Wl,--subsystem,windows -lopengl32 -mwindows
```

`gcc` can be picky about argument positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the OpenGL linker definition library `opengl32.lib` to the list of to be linked libraries.

Comment: It is in the list ... See -lopengl32

Comment: @anhadikal: Well, it doesn't get linked, that's what this message means. Could have added this to the compilation unit configuration, and not the linkage unit configuration?